# Limting Search Results in Jekyll Search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying without success to limit results in the search script included in my site.

Here is the original script:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  // Initialize lunr with the fields to be searched, plus the boost.
  window.idx = lunr(function () {
    this.field('id');
    this.field('title');
    this.field('content', { boost: 10 });
    this.field('categories');
  });

  // Get the generated search_data.json file so lunr.js can search it locally.
  window.data = $.getJSON('/search.json');

  // Wait for the data to load and add it to lunr
  window.data.then(function(loaded_data){
    $.each(loaded_data, function(index, value){
      window.idx.add(
        $.extend({ "id": index }, value)
      );
    });
  });

  // Event when the form is submitted
  $("#site_search").submit(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var query = $("#search_box").val(); // Get the value for the text field
      var results = window.idx.search(query); // Get lunr to perform a search
      display_search_results(results); // Hand the results off to be displayed
  });

  function display_search_results(results) {
    var $search_results = $("#search_results");

    // Wait for data to load
    window.data.then(function(loaded_data) {

      // Are there any results?
      if (results.length) {
        $search_results.empty(); // Clear any old results

        // Iterate over the results
        results.forEach(function(result) {
          var item = loaded_data[result.ref];

          // Build a snippet of HTML for this result
          var appendString = '<li><a href="' + item.url + '">' + item.title + '</a></li>';

          // Add the snippet to the collection of results.
          $search_results.append(appendString);
        });
      } else {
        // If there are no results, let the user know.
        $search_results.html('<li><b><u>NO RESULTS FOUND</u></b></li>');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And I've tried without success to include this limiting statement when iterating over the results:

```
        // Iterate over the results
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length && i < 5; i++)  {
         var item = loaded_date[results[i]];
```

I've fiddled around for it for quite some time, and can't seem to find what is amiss.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error were you getting, your for loop looks fine.

An alternative approach would be to use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to limit the number of results you iterate over.

```
results.slice(0, 5).forEach(function (result) {
  // snip
})
```

Replace your existing iteration over the results, where you have `results.forEach`.

This will work even if there are less than 5 results, and will take the first 5 if there are more than 5 results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Caio. Where should I place this array#slice snippet in the code above?

Comment: Also: the error I was getting was that when the search was executed, the results didn't display at all, and instead it would merely redirect to a 404 page.

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and explain where to use the call to slice.

Comment: Thanks again Oliver. The slice array worked like a charm.

Comment: I'm glad it helped solve you're problem! Maybe consider accepting this answer? ;)